# Opening a new view in a new window

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

Let's suppose I have a web application made with Backbone,
which use Backbone.Router for routing client-side pages.

Let's suppose the page layout looks like this:

```
link_1 |
link_2 | Right
link_2 |
```

And the Router is the following:

```
routes: {
    'link_:id': 'renderRight'
}
```

When the user click on `l1, l2 or l3` it opens the view on the `Right part` of the window.
But let's suppose the user want to see the Right part in a `new window`.
For how the router works, it will render the full Vies (right and left).
How can I fix this problem?

P.S.:
For creating the left part containing the link (`LinkView`) I have the following `ContainerView` which creates different instance of `LinkView` (one for each link):

```
var ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({

   // ContainerView Left Part

    addAll: function ()
    {
        this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    },

    addOne: function (task)
    {
        var view;
        view = new LinkView({ 
            model: task
        });

        this.$("#linkContainer").append(view.render().el);
    },

    // other codes

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to find a way to differentiate between `new window`, and an `existing document` with a menu.

The easiest way i can think of to do this is by using [Backbone.history](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History). When you are on the root path, you can render the menu and create an el for the right part to attach to.  Then when a linked is clicked, you catch it and have the [app router navigate](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate) to your link route. Here you can have your `renderRight` route check for an existence of an a `right-el` and attach to that, if not then this is a new page, so create an el and attach. This solves your trouble on a right-click `new-page` or a direct navigation to `root/link:id` scenario as your left menu wouldn't be existing and solve your problem of having the view render full page without it.

- root  - render menu, and create right el.
- link_:id - check for existence of el, if not create and attach to that.

**edit:** here's a sample of what i mean

```
var Application = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "root"
        'link_:id': 'renderRight',
    },


    root: function() {
        //rednder link container
        var menu = new ContainerView();
        $('body').append('<div id="linkContainer"/>','<div id="rightContainer"/>'); //create left and right container
        menu.render();
        //render initial view of right container etc..


    },

    renderRight: function () {

        if ($('#rightContainer').length == 0) $('body').append('<div id="rightContainer"/>');  //check if a rightContainer is available if not create one
        //render right container to  #rightContainer
    }

});
var app = new Application();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, +1. I am not sure to have understood what do you mean. So I added more details to my question. Can you please write just few lines of code? or change my code accordingly to your solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're doing your routes, I'm editing some code in to give you an idea though of what I mean. Also I think it would probably be a good idea to use the views [el element](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el) when you render your views.